# If time is in past

Tags: php, mysql, time

```
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

This is added to the database.

I want to select * where time = current time() or is in future.. and not in past.

I want * to be selected from DB where time is not in past.. it's in future. or present.

```
SELECT * FROM affbanners WHERE timedate=what and active=1 order by rand() limit 1
```

I want time date to be present or future and not past. that means time shouldn't have been passed yet.

`timedate` is defined by

```
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database server's clock is correct, you can simply use a query of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE <time field> >= NOW();
```

However, to keep with your question I'd go for...

```
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60); 
$queryString = 'SELECT * FROM affbanners WHERE active=1 AND timedate >= "'.$nextWeek.'"' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

That said, you'll might want to consider whether you want the banners to be selected on a "balanced" (rather than simply random) fashion. (i.e.: So that each banner gets a roughly similar view rate.)

To do this, you'd need to:

1. Add a 'view' count to each banner (which is incremented when a banner is viewed). You could of course use click throughs, etc. instead if you're tracking these.
2. Use a query like...

   SELECT * FROM affbanners WHERE active=1 AND timedate >= "'.$nextWeek.'"' ORDER BY view_count ASC LIMIT 1

By doing this, you'll balance the number of views over time.

**UPDATE**

If that's the case, I'd be very tempted to have startdate and enddate fields in your database (populated when the banner is created) and use a query like...

```
SELECT * FROM affbanners WHERE active=1 AND startdate >= NOW() AND enddate <=  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY view_count ASC LIMIT 1
```

You will of course need to track the views, click-through, etc. as well.

That said, this is very much a solved problem, so it might just be easier to use something like [OpenX](http://www.openx.org). (There's an open source version you can download.)

Comment: $nextWeek is defined while creating the banner, and not again.
So it should be timedate >= time(); ?

Comment: In that case just use "WHERE time >= NOW()". However, I'd be tempted not to attempt to store a "future" date in the banner, as it's fairly meaningless to store a relative date like this. Instead, can you store "live from" and "live until" dates? I suspect this would make your life a lot easier in the long term.

Comment: ok what i'm trying to do is..sell weekly banner rotation exposure.

Comment: The counting of impressions won't work good for me..
some banners will be purchased today and some tomorrow.
I used this timedate >= $time
$time=time();

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the current time in your PHP script and put this into $time. Then do a query like

SELECT * FROM affbanners WHERE timedate >= $time and active = 1 order by rand()

This should give you all banners having their times set to now or the future.

Comment: Yes or whatever time you want it to be.